# Import aar into titanium mobile app

Tags: android, import, module, titanium, aar

Can we import and access the .aar directly in titanium mobile app project?
If yes, how? I have tried many times to create the android module but still cannot solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should enable Hyperloop if you want to do that.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Hyperloop_Programming_Guide-section-src-46253495_AndroidHyperloopProgrammingGuide-UsingThird-partylibraries